# How to group a table by user id and get max for another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table (scrom_scoes_track table in bitnami moodle) which includes userid and value columns. Structure of the table is as follows.

[image: Table Structure]

I want to find the max mark of each user. Mark of the user can be found using the following query.

```
SELECT 
   `userid`,
   `value`
FROM 
  `mdl_scorm_scoes_track` 
WHERE 
  `element`= 'cmi.core.score.raw'
```

The result of the above query is as follows.
[image: Query result 1]

But when I tried to get max value using the following query it won't work as expected.

```
SELECT 
   `userid`,
   MAX(`value`) 
FROM 
   `mdl_scorm_scoes_track` 
WHERE 
   `element`= 'cmi.core.score.raw' 
GROUP BY 
   `userid`
```

Result of above query.
[image: Query result 2]

Here first row is userid 2 and value 50. But max value for userid 2 should be 100. (As shown in second image). Any help on this problem is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert your string into a number. Otherwise `max()` is sorting alphabetically

```
SELECT userid, max(cast(value as unsigned))
FROM mdl_scorm_scoes_track 
WHERE element = 'cmi.core.score.raw'
group by userid
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use longtext for a numeric field. 
alternatively use below

```
SELECT `userid`,MAX(cast(`value` as unsigned)) FROM `mdl_scorm_scoes_track` WHERE `element`= 'cmi.core.score.raw' GROUP BY `userid`
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but `value` is stored as `longtext`, so when you apply `max` on it, you get the "largest" value by **lexicographical** ordering. Casting it to an integer should solve the problem:

```sql
SELECT   `userid`,MAX(CAST(`value` AS UNSIGNED))
FROM     `mdl_scorm_scoes_track`
WHERE    `element`= 'cmi.core.score.raw'
GROUP BY `userid`
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the value column isn't a numeric field

Try casting the value field eg `CAST(value AS UNSIGNED)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without a GROUP BY statement. 
Just list all rows as usual, but only select the maximum value from a second copy of the table. Then link the 2 copies together.

```
SELECT 
   `userid`,
   `value`
FROM 
  `mdl_scorm_scoes_track` as outer
WHERE 
  `element`= 'cmi.core.score.raw' 
  and `value` = (
        select 
           max(`value`) 
        from 
          `mdl_scorm_scoes_track` as inner 
        where 
          inner.userid = outer.userid )
```

Comment: No. See the other answers on what the reason for wrong result is.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to convert to a number.  However, this is a case where I much prefer implicit conversion over explicit conversion:

```
SELECT userid, max(value + 0)
FROM mdl_scorm_scoes_track 
WHERE element = 'cmi.core.score.raw'
GROUP BY userid;
```

This should work for any type of number -- negative numbers and numbers with decimal points, in particular.